# web2py - is it possible to sequentially add search fields with SQLFORM.grid/smartgrid?

Tags: python, web2py

Let's say your database has N fields, and you want to display the contents with SQLFORM.grid/smartgrid, and make it possible for users to search a conjunction of some subset of that set of fields (named "field1", "field2", etc). What is a good way to implement the following:

1. by default, one field is searchable, and the user can select from a drop-down/selector menu which field that is
2. if the user wants to add another field to the search (i.e. search field1 AND field2), they can click some icon (a plus sign, for example), and another search input field will pop up
   -again, the user can select the searchable field through a selector menu
3. if necessary, repeat step 2 some number of times

In other words, the user sequentially adds search fields, and searches some conjunction of those fields. For example, the user selects "item1" as the search query in field2, adds and selects field4, and uses "thing9" as the query for field4; the search looks for rows with "item1" in field2 AND "thing9" in field4. Thanks!